# How to make divs display in one line in my situation

Tags: html, css

The "blank" is as wide as the whole page. Now I want to add a google ads div after the text "back to topic". I already try "float:left". It do not work well.

```
<div class="blank">
   <p>
     <a href="#"><&nbsp;Back to the topic</a>
   </p>
   this is google ads!
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blank p{
  width:980px;
  height:25px;
  margin:80px auto 0px auto;
}
.blank p a{
  color:#007aff;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your elements what you want to float, and wrap them with a container. After that, clear. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2x1ht1zd/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blank">
         <p><a href="#">&laquo; &nbsp;Back to the topic</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="advert"><p>this is google ads!</p></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div.container {
    width:980px;
    height:25px;
    margin:80px auto 0px auto;}

.blank {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.blank p a{
    color:#007aff;
    font-size:20px;
}

.advert {float: left;}

.clear {clear: both;}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! And can i ask, why we need the "clear?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline-block;`

**html**

```
<div class="blank">
    <p><a href="#"><&nbsp;Back to the topic</a></p>
    <div class="google-ad">this is google ads!</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.blank p{
  width:980px;
  height:25px;
  margin:80px auto 0px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blank p a{
  color:#007aff;
  font-size:20px;
}
.google-ad{
  display: inline-block;
}
```